# Offered a new position within my company weeks ago, yet I have not officially received it and am expected to perform my new duties

Tags: promotion

I have been progrmaming at my company for ~8 months now, and have been in a position unfit for the work I've been performing (Team Lead, in a callcenter). I was approached by the site director and the VP and offered a Data Analyst position, and they highlighted what they want to do and the project they want me to get started on.

That was three weeks ago, I'm expected to work on the new project, and move forward with it. Yet I do not have the new position, the pay, the tools, or the access (Getting around the strict firewall) for the job I'm performing. I've brought it up a couple times with my "new" boss, and the question has been expertly dodged.

It's not like this is a small company either, they have 1400 employees. How can I effectively, and professionally push back on this?

Comment: I can do the work, just in a very shoddy and slow fashion, without reliable access to documentation. Imagine being told to make a web app in any way you can, but you are not given an IDE, a place to host it, a database, or the ability to install any tools. The only option I could use is Google Apps Script, which is far inferior to something like ASP.NET. I made a web app in apps script before as a sort of prototype, since it cleanly integrated into Google services, and that's all I've been able to use since then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How can I effectively, and professionally push back on this?

One thing you could do is write up a project plan, this is really the first stage before anything can be done. You need a clear and actionable plan itemising everything you need and the steps needed to accomplish the task/s. Once you have that you have something to discuss in detail with the bosses, at the very least it shows you know what you're doing (because they might not know what is needed) and you're ready to do the work. This may well be the tipping point that gets everything started.

Have an easily understood summary at the start with the salient points and timeframes. See if you can get the boss to read it and ok it, then ask when they want you to get started.

Then while that is sorted out you make sure you get the promotion that goes with it.

To me it looks like they're purposely putting you off while they figure out how to get the project started properly if at all, and they don't want to pay you extra until it's all ready to go. So there is probably external reasons they are waiting on which are out of their control. But that's just my idea.

In reality, you never bank on a verbal promise from people who do not have a vested personal interest in it and even then keep your fingers crossed. 8 months is not a long time in the big picture.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. A bit more info that might give you some insight, the leadership that wants to start the project has no experience managing development. This company may have 1400 employees, but maybe 1 in every 300 is either IT or a dev, there is absolutely no internal tooling what so ever, and IT is treated like a necessary evil rather than a boon. My new boss assumes that I can push out a new tool for each team at a rate of one per day, and does not want to hear otherwise. There is a pretty big disconnect to begin with.

Comment: ouch, sounds like they have no idea what they're doing. You'll need to write up the project plan properly for a start. You done that before?

Comment: I honestly have not done that before, but I have written up a fairly comprehensive plan that details the challenges, processes, and expectations of this project. Though he has declined to read it as it is too long (8 pages).

Comment: good, now make a summary, never show a challenge without a solution, get it down to one page with the rest for clarification and see what happens. You always need a summary, non technical people have no interest in anything else to start with.

Comment: So, an update on this. I was eventually told they don't have it in the budget to provide me with the position or tools (Like any IDE, or unblocking stackoverflow...etc), but I am still expected to move forward with the work.